# Changing the position of virtual column phpgrid

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jqgrid, phpgrid

In phpgrid I have added a virtual column (column not existing in db) using the `add_column` method. But the problem is I cannot make it appear it in the first position(i.e first column of the table). Documentation for the `add_column` method says that it will be appended at the end of the other columns [add_method for phpgrid](http://phpgrid.com/documentation/add_column/). Is it possible to add it in the first column/position? I tried various jquery hacks but none seems to be useful.

Below is the code for add_column

**PHP code**

```
$dg->add_column("custom", array('name'          => 'custom',
                                'index'         => 'custom',
                                'width'         => '100',
                                'formatter'     => '###customAction###',
                                'formatoptions' => array('keys' => true, 'editbutton' => true, 'delbutton' => true)), 'Custom Action');
```

**JAVASCRIPT code**

```
function customAction(cellValue, options, rowdata) {
        output = '<span class="custom-action"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus custom" data-transaction-id="' + options.rowId + '"></i></span>';
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter indicates the column position.

```
$dg->add_column('total', array('name'=>'total', 'index'=>'total', 'width'=>'100', 'align'=>'right', 'sortable'=>false,
    'formatter'=>$col_formatter),
        'Total (Virtual)', 0);
```

This should put the virtual column to the index 0, the first column.

Comment: Column comes in the first position but the data in other column is messed up, in the table header I can see the title of the column but cannot see the data in the table.